# how to make useReactToPrint get the last update(state)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, updates, use-ref, react-to-print

I want to print the facture of selling , for that i used useReactToPrint but the problem is that it takes the last update of my values, for example if i add two numbersin the selling price field it only shows the first one in the print pdf page, i think the problem is with the useRef ... I want the handlePrint function to be excuted at every update .Here is some part of the code:

```
     const invoiceRef: MutableRefObject<any> = useRef();
  const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
    content: () => invoiceRef.current,
    removeAfterPrint: true,
  });


  const printSellingInvoice: React.FC<ISellingInvoiceRequest> = (props) => {
const intl = useIntl();

return (
  <div className="invoice">
  .
  .
  .
   
  </div>
);
```

};

Comment: Use state instead

Comment: How to use useState with reactToPrint